# Remove old fillRect, clearRect not working?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to get this code to work, I'm trying to make a game where you click on disappearing rectangles, and have made some good progress, but my issue is that when the rectangle disappears the 'hitbox' for it is still there, so to speak.

I'm still new with canvases, but I think it has something to do with the clearRect method on context, but I'm not sure. Here's my code:

```
<script>
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 800;
const CANVAS_WIDTH = 1200;

var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    elemLeft = elem.offsetLeft,
    elemTop = elem.offsetTop,
    context = elem.getContext('2d'),
    elements = [];


// Game vars
var score = 0;
var interval = 1000;
var wid = 150;
var hei = 100;

// Add event listener for `click` events.
elem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var x = event.pageX - elemLeft,
        y = event.pageY - elemTop;
    console.log(`Clicked at (${x}, ${y})`);


    // Collision detection between clicked offset and element.
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
        if (y > element.top && y < element.top + element.height 
            && x > element.left && x < element.left + element.width) {
                score += 1;
                wid -= 5/wid;
                hei -= 5/hei;
                console.log(`Score: ${score}`);
        }
    });

}, false);


// Add element.
function addElements(){
    var wp = Math.floor(Math.random() * CANVAS_WIDTH);
    var hp = Math.floor(Math.random() * CANVAS_HEIGHT);

    // Get rekt
    elements.push({
        colour: '#05EFFF',
        width: wid,
        height: hei,
        top: hp,
        left: wp
    });
    // Render
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT)
        context.fillStyle = element.colour;
        context.fillRect(element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);
    });
}

(function myLoop (i) {          
   setTimeout(function () {   
      addElements();          //  your code here                
      if (--i) myLoop(i);      //  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
   }, interval)
})(100);       


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never remove any elements what so ever.

Try adding a `console.log(elements.length);` inside `myLoop` and watch as the counter goes up and up :)

One quickfix is just to reassign `elements` to an empty array in the top of `addElements`

```
elements = [];
```

Comment: Gotchaaa, I'm sure you could notice I copied and pasted the majority of this code, I didn't even notice they were pushing it all to a list. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it did, my account is brand new so apologies, I am unable to upvote your answer :(